# Serializing while closing a window

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, event-handling, code-behind

Trying serialize when I close the window. I get this runtime error:

> An unhandled exception of type `System.NotSupportedException` occurred
>   in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.

This happens in two separate instances:

1. Closing the window by using the exit button (top-right corner),
2. closing the window by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

On each respective instance one. No source code available, two `this.Close()` was highlighted when the error was raised (see `KeysDown` method in `Window.xaml.cs`).

Code (curtailed to fit this query):

**Window.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SessionManager SM { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //code
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registered to MainWindow.KeysDown Event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="kea"></param>
    private void KeysDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs kea)
    {
        switch (kea.Key)
        {
            case Key.Escape:
                this.Close();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void SaveSession(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        SM.SaveSession();
    }
}
```

**SessionManager.cs** (I had problems with the class variables, so I did not omit them):

```
[Serializable]
    public class SessionManager : DependencyObject
    {
        [NonSerialized]
        public static readonly DependencyProperty currentSessionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("currentSession", typeof(Session),
            typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
        [NonSerialized]
        public static readonly DependencyProperty startTimeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("strStartTime", typeof(string),
            typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now.ToString()));

        private static string SM_FILE = "SessionManager.bin";

        /// <summary>
        /// Holds a list of all comments made within the session
        /// </summary>
        public List<string> Sessions { get; private set; }
        [NonSerialized]
        private DateTime _dtStartTime;

        public SessionManager()
        {
            //code
        }


        #region Methods

        public void SaveSession()
        {
            if (currentSession.timeEntries.Count != 0)
            {
                currentSession.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                Sessions.Remove(currentSession.Name);
            }

            //Serialize the SessionManager
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new FileStream(SM_FILE, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            formatter.Serialize(stream,this);
            stream.Close();
        }

        public void OpenSession(int index)
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new FileStream(Sessions[index], FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
            currentSession=(Session)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**Session.cs** (I had problems with the class variables, so I did not omit them):

```
[Serializable]
public class Session : DependencyObject
{
    [NonSerialized]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty nameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("name", typeof(string),
        typeof(Session), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    [NonSerialized]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty totalTimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("totalTime", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(Session),
        new PropertyMetadata(TimeSpan.Zero));

    public Session()
    {
        //code
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream= new FileStream(Name,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any events registered in your code with '+='?

Comment: I thought that class that derives from DependencyObject cannot be serialized.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294650/can-a-class-derived-from-dependencyobject-marked-as-serializable

Comment: Event Closing should be what you need.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Besides any other problems, registering the dependency properties in class SessionManager with MainWindow as owner type is wrong. It should read `DependencyProperty.Register("currentSession", typeof(Session), typeof(SessionManager), ...);`

Comment: _"The given path's format is not supported."_ -- this would imply some kind of problem with the file path that you are trying to write to in the `Save` method: possibly invalid filename characters, or a permissions issue.

Comment: @Clemens: oops didn't notice that. A while ago, I decided to move some stuff around to make it more organized, and I guess that was an artifact of the old software architecture. Will fix ASAP.

Comment: @StevenRands: I removed a touch too much code from **Session.cs**. In the constructor the Name variable is assigned a value that will later be the name of the .bin file: Name = DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".bin";

Comment: I suspect that is your problem then. `DateTime.Now.ToString()` will probably return a string with a `:` in it, which is an invalid character for a filename.

Comment: @StevenRands: Yes, I fixed that now. I'm back to the  DependencyOjbect issue. Thanks for the help.